# Determine all points where $f(x+iy) = 2xy + i(x+\frac 2 3 y^3)$ is differentiable in $\mathbb C$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function $f : \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ given by $f(x+iy) = 2xy + i(x+\frac 2 3 y^3)$.

I want to determine all points at which $f$ is differentiable as a complex function.

To do this, I must decide the points $z_0$ for which the limit $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {f(z_0 + h) -f(z_0)} {h}$$ exist.

I've tried to evaluate this limit directly, but it gets very complicated. Is there an easier way ?

Should I decompose $f$ into sums and products of other functions ?

Comment: Some books define "$f$ is differentiable as a complex function at $z_0$" as "$f$ fulfills the Cauchy-Riemann equations at $z_0$". See if that is not the case for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect, that this question asks you to find out for which complex numbers the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) hold. So, you need to calculate the partial derivatives and solve the equalities finding out which $z$ make them true:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$
and 
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$

In your case, $u(x, y) = 2xy$ and $v(x, y) = x + \frac{2}{3}y^3$, which makes your $f(x, y) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y)$.

I don't think that finding the limit is the right approach.

Comment: Thank you, this made it much easier.